# Ubuntu sometimes sleeps after power state changes

Tags: 17.10, suspend, power-management, laptop

Sometimes, when I boot into Ubuntu (I dual boot Windows 10), plugging in or taking out the laptop charger will cause the computer to go to sleep. I tested it out and found that these lines occur in `dmesg` when I plug the power in:

```
[ 9093.169515] atkbd serio0: Spurious ACK on isa0060/serio0. Some program might be trying to access hardware directly.
[ 9093.200810] atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (raw set 2, code 0x12b on isa0060/serio0).
[ 9093.200813] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes 2b <keycode>' to make it known.
```

When it occurs, it occurs every time I manipulate the charger plug. But if it doesn't occur on a particular boot, it will never happen on that boot, as far as I can tell. Is this something I can fix?

Other info:

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 on a Razer Blade 2017.

Edit: I have discovered some more `dmesg` lines that differ between a "good" boot where the problem doesn't occur, and a "bad" boot where it does:

```
 pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
 pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=00e5(Transmitter ID)
 error status/mask=00001000/00002000
 Replay Timer Timeout
```

These lines repeat multiple times per minute, and sometimes multiple times per second, but are never present in a "good" boot.